# Allocating memory for a point (enums)

Tags: c++, pointers, enums

I am in the process of creating a asteroid game.  I started off with using variables but now I need to convert one into a point(the SHIP).  In my header file it is declared as 
`enum SpaceObjType { SHIP, ASTEROID, PHOTON_TORPEDO };` and in my game.cpp I declare 
`SpaceObject* SHIP(SHIP, 20, { 200,200 }, { 0.0 }, 90);` (the stuff after is

```
SpaceObject::SpaceObject(SpaceObjType type, double radius, Point location, Point velocity, double angle)
{
    this->type = type;
    this->radius = radius;
    this->location = location;
    this->velocity = velocity;
    this->angleDeg = angle;

}
```

For some reason the type and radius are giving me an error: 
a value of type "SpaceObjType" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "SpaceObject*" (for type)
and
Too many initializer values (for radius)

Do I need to allocate memory? If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `SpaceObject* SHIP(SHIP, 20, { 200,200 }, { 0.0 }, 90);` is invalid, replace `{ 200,200 }` by `Point(200,200)` and `{ 0.0 }` by `Point(0,0)` supposing *Point* have the right constructor. Also do not name your variable SHIP being an enum item

Comment: { 200, 200 } is actually valid as of C++11, as is { 0, 0 } although OP mistakenly wrote { 0.0 } I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the SpaceObject variable you are instantiating is the same as one of the enum values. When calling the constructor, the compiler thinks your passing a value of SpaceObject* where it expects one of SpaceObjectType. Try changing the name of your SpaceObject variable to ship (lowercase) or something else.

You can prevent name ambiguity of enums by using enum classes in the future.